# Angular 16, parent component is not passing data to the second child component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I got an Angular 16.1 application. This application has a parent component with two children components:

Parent component inbox.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'inbox',
  templateUrl: './templates/inbox.html'
})
export class Inbox implements OnInit   {
  tableRowsQuantity : number;
  UserName : string;

  constructor(private router: Router, private http:HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadUserName();
    this.loadInboxRowsQuantity(); // It uses http request by jquery with async:false
  }
}
```

inbox.html:

```
<div>
    {{inboxRowsQuantity}}  <---  It shows the quantity. For this example, the value is 5
    <childUser>
            [UserName]="UserName"
    </childUser>
<br><br>
    <childInbox> 
           [inboxRowsQuantity]="inboxRowsQuantity">   <--- this is the instruction that it's not working. It's not passing the value
    </childInbox>
</div>
```

Child component 1:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'childUser',
  templateUrl: '../templates/childUser.html'
})
export class ChildUser implements OnInit   {
  @Input() UserName = '';

  constructor(private router: Router, private http:HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
  
  ngOnInit() {
         ....

  }
}
```

childUser.html:

```
<div>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%">
    <tr>
      <th>User name:</th>
      <td>&nbsp;{{UserName|titlecase}}</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Child component 2:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'childInbox',
  templateUrl: '../templates/childInbox.html'
})
export class ChildInbox implements OnInit   {

  @Input() inboxRowsQuantity :number = 0;

  constructor(private router: Router, private http:HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
  
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('inboxRowsQuantity is:',this.inboxRowsQuantity);  // always gives zero
    
  }
  
}
```

childInbox.html:

```
<ul style="padding: 0px;">
    <li class="menu-item">
        <span style="list-style-type:none;"><i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>Inbox</span>
        <span class="badge">{{inboxRowsQuantity}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I will mention the following steps of loading the page:

1. inbox.ts is processed. In this file tableRowsQuantity and UserName are obtained.
2. childUser.ts is processed and chilUser.html is shown with user name value.
3. childInbox.ts is processed. but {{inboxRowsQuantity}} of childInbox.html was not updated.
4. {{inboxRowsQuantity}} is just shown in inbox.html but childboxInbox.html keeps showing zero.

It seems templates are loaded asynchronously. Besides, childUser.html is showing the correct information but childInbox.html isn't.

What is it missing for this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML template is incorrect. The attributes for your child components are not part of the tag.

Update your HTML to the following:

```html
<div>
    <childUser [UserName]="UserName">
    </childUser>
<br><br>
    <childInbox [inboxRowsQuantity]="inboxRowsQuantity">
    </childInbox>
</div>
```

See how I moved the `[UserName]` and `[inboxRowsQuantity]` inside the brackets for the childUser and childInbox tags?

Comment: It working. Question. 1) Why console.log('inboxRowsQuantity is:',this.inboxRowsQuantity); returns undefined?

Comment: The ngOnInit method only runs once, right at the start of the component lifecycle. Since it runs right at the start, the input hasn't been populated with data yet, so you need to wait for the input to receive data, and then you should see it in the console. My suggestion is to use ngOnChanges instead of ngOnInit, then you will see your console.log print every time the input changes.